# Loading a file that defines values overwrites top-level bindings

Tags: scheme

If I have a file test.scm:

```
(define foo 5)
```

and then using the REPL:

```
(define foo 2)

foo
==> 2

(define bar
  (lambda ()
    (load "test.scm")
    foo))

foo
==> 2

(bar)
==> 5

foo
==> 5
```

In other words, loading a file in one lexical context allows the bindings to escape to the top level. Why is this so, and is there a way to include another file as per C `#include`, i.e. execute the commands as if they were spliced into the code at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code executed by `load` were able to access the lexical context of the `load` form, it wouldn't be a *lexical* context.

The situation would be somewhat different if `load` were a macro rather than a function—but even then, standard R5RS macros are hygienic and cannot easily mess with the lexical context.

However, you could write a `defmacro`-style macro that does what you ask for by reading a file and returning a `begin` form containing everything read from the file.

#### Example code:

```
(define-macro (include file)
  (let ((read-forms
         (lambda ()
           (let loop ((forms '()))
             (let ((form (read)))
               (if (eof-object? form)
                   (reverse forms)
                   (loop (cons form forms))))))))
    (with-input-from-file file
      (lambda ()
        (cons 'begin (read-forms))))))
```

Note that `define-macro` is non-standard.  You will have to figure out whether and how it can be made to work depending on your Scheme implementation.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Well, `define-macro`, `defmacro`, etc. are not in my implementation (MIT/GNU), so the best I could do was a macro that appends whatever code you want to the end of the `begin` form, then evaluates it in a clone of the top-level environment. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Arafinwe MIT/GNU Scheme has [explicit-renaming macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Explicit-Renaming.html#Explicit-Renaming), which are basically a superset of `defmacro`.

Answer (score 1):

see 
http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-user/Loading-Files.html

```
procedure: load filename [environment [syntax-table [purify?]]]
```

"Environment, if given, is the environment to evaluate the file in; if not given the current REPL environment is used."

that means that the file is evaluated directly into the repl and not in the lambda closure.

**EDIT**
see this question on SO [(load "file.scm") in a New Environment in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335595/load-file-scm-in-a-new-environment-in-scheme) how a new environment can be made.

Comment: I'm still not sure how I'd implement the "bar" procedure. Where do I put the code that should be executed in the new environment?